# Rsync directory error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, rsync, remote

I wanted to copy files that are made 15 and more days ago.
Here is the code im currently using

```
rsync -RDa0P \
    --files-from=<(find /vmail/folder1/ -mtime +15 -print0) \
    . root@202.60.9.11:/vmail/folder1/
```

The `find` part did show all the files:

```
/vmail/folder1/folder11/file15,
/vmail/folder1/folder11/file16
```

but when the code above is issued, it gives an error `failed: No such file or directory (2)`. And the directory was changed, `root` was added :

```
rsync: link_stat "/root/vmail/folder1/folder11/cur/ failed: No such file or directory (2)"
```

Am i missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-R is for relative path name.

You are probably in the /root directory, adapt your command or move to /

Comment: Great! This fixed the problem. Didn't think it has to do with my current directory